# java - openjdk8 - How to set BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR on BufferedImage?

Tags: java

I have a 1st BufferedImage from a sub part of image. I want set `BufferedImage` 
`imageType` to `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` for use to `openjdk8`.

```
    final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) Context.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    FileUtils.forceMkdir(new File(System.getProperty(USER_DIR) + File.separator + DOWNLOADED_FILES_FOLDER));

    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(screenshot);
    BufferedImage fullImg = ImageIO.read(in);

    // Get the location of element on the page
    Point point = element.getLocation();

    // Get width and height of the element
    int eleWidth = element.getSize().getWidth();
    int eleHeight = element.getSize().getHeight();

    // Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
    BufferedImage eleScreenshot = fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth, eleHeight);

    // ????? BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(eleScreenshot.getWidth(), eleScreenshot.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

    ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "jpg", new File(System.getProperty(USER_DIR) + File.separator + DOWNLOADED_FILES_FOLDER + File.separator + screenName + ".jpg");
```

Comment: I am afraid there is no way to change an image type after it is constructed (image type is only an argument for constructor) - maybe you can create an image of desired type and draw the original onto it (using its `createGraphics()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `BufferedImage` constructor with `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` + copy of data via `Graphics` object.

```
BufferedImage eleScreenshot = fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth, eleHeight);
ImageIO.write(convertType(eleScreenshot, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR), "jpg", new File(System.getProperty(USER_DIR) + File.separator + DOWNLOADED_FILES_FOLDER + File.separator + screenName + ".jpg"));

 private BufferedImage convertType(BufferedImage eleScreenshot, int type) {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(eleScreenshot.getWidth(), eleScreenshot.getHeight(), type);
    Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(eleScreenshot, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return bi;
}
```